# No "Altruist" badge awarding notification in achievements popup

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog, bounty-badges

Today I [got "Altruist" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/altruist?userid=339911), but I've not been notified about it and I don't see it in Achievements popup:

> [image: Achievements popup]